# Hooking up a BLDC motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

[image]

[image]

[image: Toggle switch connections]

[image: Potentiometer connections]

Toggle Switch Connections[image]

I want a welding turntable able to turn 500 pound chunks of metal with room to spare. The vertical load with the table horizontal is no problem, it's when I went horizontal with material offset the centerline. ie. saddles, fittings and such, that I smoked the brushes and commutator on the $1800 turntable I had.

I told a vendor what I needed and showed them the speed controller I had, they matched up the motor, BLDC driver and power supply. I assumed matching the speed controller I already had.

I figured when I bought this it would come with wiring schematics, blue wire goes here, green wire goes there type of thing.

I tried hooking it all up , but I'm in over my head. I found a diagram for the controller that shows where to connect the motor to it which is how I was able to run the wires you see in pictures.

The motor to the controller shows yellow, green and blue to U V W, but my motor has yellow green and red. I connected the red to where it shows blue, just because it seems right.
Now I am not sure how to connect the speed controller, I'm stuck. Please help me.

- How would I connect a toggle switch to change directions?
- How do I control speed?
- Would I be better off using a VFD?

PStechPaul has recently suggested I can probably apply voltage from a microcontroller DAC or filtered PWM, which really means nothing to me: still in the same boat, not knowing how to connect it.

A [hyperlink](http://zgbjdj.com/news2.asp?id=18847) was shared in the comments to a distributors' site that has good information on it.

Here is a link to a video of operation.

[Trying to figure out why my BDLC isn't running in 2 directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeeaS.jpg)

Diagram of BLDC driver connections:
[image: diagram of BLDC driver connections]

Power Supply:
[image: Power Supply]

Speed controller:
[image: Speed controller]

Speed controller:
[image: Speed controller]

Motor connections on motor controller:
[image: Motor connections on motor controller]

Motor controller:
[image: Motor Controller]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141543/discussion-on-question-by-anthony-arnone-ii-hooking-up-a-bldc-motor).

Comment: Is the sensor wiring correct? I would guess that Hu/Hv/Hw colours should match U/V/W. I don't think it matters if you swap the phases around (e.g. swap green and yellow). I *do* think it matters if the power wires don't match the sensor wires.

Comment: (@user253751: in the imgur post, there's an image of the sensor cable using the conventional colours connected correctly. On a welder's workbench.)

Comment: (@user253751: I had the idea to change the 3 phase wires. Like on an AC motor, switch the legs and the rotation will change. Doesn't work that way.)

Comment: it does work that way! BLDC motors are a kind of AC motor with the wrong label on purpose... don't ask...

Comment: I did not, I know of no switch that would change all the wires needed for it to be practical. The information on the hyper link suggests it can be changed.

Comment: information on the hyper link suggests it can be changed without switching the phases, just a shot.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a simple potentiometer connected between COM and V+, with the wiper to Ve. There is also an enable input (EN) that is connected to COM. The pot might be between 2k and 10k, so 5k should be about right.

The diagram also shows connections from Hall effect sensors, H+, H-, Hu, Hv, and Hw. These would provide speed and position feedback. It will probably work OK without them. Otherwise, it will be necessary to contact the manufacturer of the controller and/or motor to obtain a compatible sensor module.

Comment: If the speed controller I have was a potentiometer I would be golden. It's not though, what I have and is needed for the application, so it can be timed to go slower at first for a pre-set amount of time before it reaches it's maximum set value. The diagram shows 4 connections, I have 8 wires. I bought the controller, motor and power supply at the same time, but it came with no diagrams. I have had to find them. I told them what –

Comment: I needed and showed them the speed controller I had, they matched up the motor, controller and power supply to the speed controller I already had. All I need to know is where to connect the 2-inverse limit wires, the 2 positive limit wires, where to put the + - wires for the motor, pretty sure the power wires come from the power supply.

Comment: That controller is for a brushed DC motor, and cannot be used for a BLDC motor. I think all you need is a potentiometer, which you can purchase anywhere for a few dollars. If you need special functions like programmed time and speed, you can probably apply voltage from a microcontroller DAC or filtered PWM.

Comment: @PStechPau Yah, I built a gaming computer around 15 years ago that still up and running because the instructions said tab A goes into slot A and showed pictures. Guess I am stuck with basic controls. How would I connect a toggle switch to change directions.

Comment: There is "DIR" terminal that can be switched to GND. The controller label shows the connections. It looks like it might be for a momentary pushbutton, however.

Comment: This was shared in the comments before this was put in chat. Describes how to do it.  http://zgbjdj.com/news2.asp?id=18847

Comment: At least I think it does, the translation isn't the greatest for me.

Comment: Tried to edit this , guess I have no idea how to. Herer is a link to a video of the motor running both ways, works on way but the alarm light comes on the controller after I turn the potentiometer so far and starts to make a sound before it shuts down.  https://imgur.com/a/YeVnwxK

Comment: Are you sure that one end of the potentiometer goes to COMMON, and the other end to V+, with the wiper arm to Ve? Use a DMM to check the voltage from V+ to COM, and from Ve to COM. As you rotate the pot from end to end it should vary smoothly from 0 to 12V or 24V.

Comment: It looks like you have one end of the pot connected to white (which seems to be EN) and also gray (I can't tell what that is). COM (yellow) seems to go only to one arm of the switch, which gets connected to DIR in one position.

Comment: I'd expect V+ to be a "logic supply voltage", say, 5V. Brown (not grey) looks COM, white ENable, blue V+ (see image above those showing the potentiometer&switch assembly).

Comment: I am not sure of anything at this moment, heh. I just connected it the way the diagram showed. Yellow and red (com/DIR) is the only direction the motor will travel. I was told to take off the red jumper, I did, and it does the same thing. V+ to COM stays at 4.83 volts, Ve to COM is 0 to 4.83 volts (the motor is 5 volts).

Comment: yup, what greybeard said.

Answer (score 0):

I see no *useful* way to control a BLDC driver using the remote of a brushed DC motor speed controller.

That looks serious(ly costly) equipment:
2kWatts is a lot when there are ~20 W turntables.

That aside, you can try to use the speed controller's output to generate a signal for Ve:
Connect the BLDC driver's COM to the speed controller's 0V/GND/COM.
I'd try a voltage divider 12 kOhms to motor+, two anti-serial 22 μF capacitors parallel 1.5 kOhms to COM - note that this may work for one direction, if that.

Comment: No rigging. Being 100% sure they actually matched everything up to the speed controller I had and not having searched for better instructions until I had everything and started trying to wire it together, I never read that it was for a brushed motor. Boo, Nice catch. What would you suggest with similar functionality. Not sure a VFD will do it, will it? Fairly costly, about $695 for the 1.5kw motor the controller and a NMRV90 gear reducer, less than you would expect. This is supposed to be able to turn 500# with room to spare. I smoked the brushes and com. on the turntable I had, it was $1800.

Comment: Laser, don't I wish, I weld production parts from my home on a 1099. No sir. 500# chunks of metal, vertical is no problem, it's when I went horizontal with material offset the centerline. ie. saddles, fittings and such. I tried to be more concise about what I needed at the top. Someone edited it. Would this work? I'd still need help wiring it I am sure. https://www.amazon.com/VIGELA-Universal-Frequency-Converter-Applicable/dp/B09Y4J87P9/ref=sr_1_5?crid=P4BFP3YXR3FK&keywords=vfd%2B48%2Bvolt%2B60%2BA&qid=1672041925&sprefix=vfd%2B48%2Bvolt%2B60%2Ba%2Caps%2C114&sr=8-5&th=1

Comment: VFD's usually are for driving ASMs.

Comment: That has been my problem. Thanks to you, now I know the speed control can't work. PStechPaul has recently suggested I can probably apply voltage from a microcontroller DAC or filtered PWM. Which really means nothing to me and would be in the same boat, not knowing how to connect it.

Comment: `apply [the] filtered PWM` from your brushed motor controller is what I sketch in my answer. Going to try and suggest an edit to your question - will probably take about half an hour.

Comment: @PStechPaul or anyone really willing. This sight (once translated) says how to connect everything. Can you please read it over and in "dummy terms" tell me how to connect a toggle switch 
 for forward and backwards. In short it says to DIR to COM = reverse, DIR to V+ = forward. Does that basically mean I could disconnect the DIR wire and touch the COM or v+ to change directions? I really can't afford to burn anything up. zgbjdj.com/news2.asp?id=18847

Comment: `can't afford to burn anything` that's one reason I answered this sketchily: Without *on-site* "expertise"/competence, there is a *real* chance of costly mishap. Local educational institutions may be in holiday, but BLDC motors have become common - in (scale/functional) models too. Nobody in the neighbourhood or family with a keen interest in model (or pedelec) electronics? A power supply able to limit current to a, say, 1 Ampere level would go a long way to limit disaster should it strike, lowering voltage to 36...40 V welcome. Did you find&read manuals for the ZM-6650A?

Comment: (*touching wires* to potentials with kWatts equipment rubs me the wrong way. I'd hope it works as sketched near the terminal: A switch (toggle for starters) to purposefully connect and disconnect DIR and COM.)

Comment: Not to worry, me typing that was a way to show how communicate to me the way to connect a toggle switch. I understand the dangers of connecting dead wire to a live terminal. I don't know what the symbols mean on the controller enough to assume anything.

Comment: Growing up it was one of my jobs to connect the family travel trailer to city power before the breaker (stupid of my father but it was my job), since then I have wired 3 phase machines to 500 kw generators with cam locks, wired lights, plugs, and built a few junction boxes, used a microwaves transformer to make a Lichtenberg burner for wood ect.. I know the dangers.

Comment: added a picture

Comment: (In the pictures, I see no indication DIR should be connected to V+, but it *is* mentioned as an alternative in translate.google.com's translation.)

Comment: So would the picture I posted of the toggle switch be correct? Given the toggle switch is set up like that. I have multiple types. Alternative? DIR to V+ is for forward, and DIR to com is reverse is it not? Or did I read it wrong?

Comment: *Looks* good to go. Get a manual!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141665/discussion-between-anthony-arnone-ii-and-greybeard).